# ARSKView snapshot iOS

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit

Has anyone had any luck with taking screenshots of the `ARSKView` in ARKit projects?

I tried something like this:

```
if let sc = view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sc.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
        sc.drawHierarchy(in: sc.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot!, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

But the output is a black image.

On Apple's example, they are using `ARSCNView`, where they can call a snapshot function and it does everything automatically.

I'm using SpriteKit not SceneKit, so in spriteKit there is no snapshot method.

Answer (score 1):

- I also got the black screen when using `drawHeirarchy(in:afterScreenUpdates:)` on the `ARSKView`
- Another approach that failed for me: Using the ARSession property `(ARFrame *)currentFrame` - converting the pixel buffer `capturedImage` to a `UIImage` but this just shows the image of the real world, it doesn't include the sprites.
- What worked for me was just taking a screenshot from the View Controller view instead of the `ARSKView`.
- It's still a possibility to just switch to SceneKit since you can still use SpriteKit as a material on an `SCNNode`. SceneKit comes with nice stuff like snapshot as well.
- There are also open-source implementations like ARVideoKit https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit as well